# HTML tags in the body are not showing up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36697076/revisions) on SO the author was asking a question with the following text:

> between `>` and `</` of any tag.

Those "greater then" and "less then" symbols are showing up only if you backtick them. Otherwise the output will be:

> between > and of any tag.

It seems that the `</` string without backticks is not being escaped.

Comment: Apparently I've already typed up an answer to this, so I'm going to stop typing here and just link to the question on Meta SE: [Inequalities stripped as HTML tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217926/inequalities-stripped-as-html-tags)

Comment: Yeap, that's the essentially the same bug (+1). I searched before creating, but apparently formed my query differently.

Comment: BTW the accepted answer to the other question says that (real) HTML tags can never have a space between the < and the tag name. This isn't true.

Comment: Well, I guess someone asking a question on math.se.com would probably not care if *real* HTML can have a space or not :)

Comment: @Uzbekjon Everybody posting to SE should have a minimal knowledge of how HTML works! Seriously. I see so many examples, e.g. people using < > for quotes, posting about how they press the <q> key, things like that, and then wondering why the <q> doesn't show up in the post. If they knew about HTML, and simply said the "q" key, that wouldn't happen.

Comment: I would agree if SE communities were limited to web development. But there are other communities such as Christianity, Travel, Biology, etc. We can't expect everybody to have a minimal knowledge of HTML. I agree, that would be great, but ...